# Apache2 on Ubuntu EC2 not read envvars

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have small problem with Apache2 on my EC2 instance. I install LAMP but when I call `apache2` I receive this:

```
[Thu Dec 03 22:06:56.100599 2015] [core:warn] [pid 31235] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Thu Dec 03 22:06:56.100721 2015] [core:warn] [pid 31235] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Thu Dec 03 22:06:56.100777 2015] [core:warn] [pid 31235] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Thu Dec 03 22:06:56.100824 2015] [core:warn] [pid 31235] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Thu Dec 03 22:06:56.100871 2015] [core:warn] [pid 31235] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Thu Dec 03 22:06:56.105835 2015] [core:warn] [pid 31235] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Thu Dec 03 22:06:56.105971 2015] [core:warn] [pid 31235] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Thu Dec 03 22:06:56.106008 2015] [core:warn] [pid 31235] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

I try everything - `apt-get update`, install LAMP one more time but nothing are working. How can I set this config variables?

Yes I try to find solution in Internet, but I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling Apache directly from the binary doesn't include the envvars which makes it throw your error.

Start, restart and stop Apache from the init script, either with

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

OR

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: I have http://pastebin.com/4bQhAX5y

Comment: Which Apache version are you running?

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Oct 14 2015 14:20:21

Comment: Restart with this `$ sudo apachectl restart`

Comment: I try restart, reinstall but it not working for me. I executed also `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`, but when I run `apache2` I still get errors about unknown variables.

Comment: When you run `apache2` you are calling the binary directly which is not loaded with the envars and will throw same error you posted. What do you see when you restart?

Comment: * Restarting web server apache2
   ...done. - only this message

Comment: It's restarted and should be running, what else is your issue?

Comment: When I want to visit my site I don't have any response - maybe is my mistake and apache2 is working fine, but I'm stupid noob and I can't access to my site

Comment: Apache is certainly not the problem as it is running, check your firewalls if its accepting incoming connections to port 80

Comment: Okay yes, it's my fault. I'm new in amazon and here is answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004159/opening-port-80-ec2-amazon-web-services

Comment: And that solves it :)